# Inserting text and image using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am struggling with inserting an image and text on the same page of the pdf file. I am using pdfbox library. **Apache PDFBox 2.0.24**. I can add images and text separately, but not to the existing page. If I add an image first, when I try to add text, the image is missed. Please share your thoughts, codes and experiences with me.

Comment: Yes, please supply the smallest possible code that shows the problem.

Comment: Let me ***guess***: You're using separate `PDPageContentStream` instances for adding image and text, and you use the `PDPageContentStream(PDDocument document, PDPage sourcePage)` constructor? If I guessed correctly, please simply read the JavaDocs of the `PDPageContentStream` constructors and choose one that matches your requirements. And if I guessed wrong, see this as an argument in favor of supplying your pivotal code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.